# How to assert only 1 value from multiple possible keys in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a JSON as mentioned below

- def name = {"firstName": "John", "middleName": "M", "lastName": "Jacob"}

I need to apply assertion that my text (ex "John") should be present in any one of the 3 keys in above JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, this is actually a one-liner:

```
* match karate.valuesOf(name) contains 'John'
```